# How to get_attribute('innerHTML') from a list of URLs - Selenium?

Tags: python, loops, selenium

I am web scraping using Selenium in Python. And I'm using the xpath to extract part of the contents for the website.

I want to know how to use a loop extract a list of URLs and save them into a dictionary.

```
mylist_URLs = ['https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/own-disp? action=getowner&CIK=0001560258',
'https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/own-disp?action=getissuer&CIK=0000034088',
'https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/own-disp?action=getissuer&CIK=0001048911']
```

My coding below only works for 1 url...

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'xxx\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/own-disp?action=getowner&CIK=0000104169')

driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div/table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td')[0].get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple for each loop with WebDriverWait to make sure the table is loaded before getting the innerHTML.

**Add below imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Script:**

```
mylist_URLs = ['https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/own-disp? action=getowner&CIK=0001560258',
'https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/own-disp?action=getissuer&CIK=0000034088',
'https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/own-disp?action=getissuer&CIK=0001048911']
# open the browser
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'xxx\chromedriver.exe')
# iterate through all the urls
for url in mylist_URLs:
    print(url)
    driver.get(url)
    # wait for the table to present
    element = WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td)[1]"))
    # now get the element innerHTML
    print(element.get_attribute('innerHTML')))
```

Comment: I received the "SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
 #element.get_attribute('innerHTML')". I also found "SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
element = WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td)[1]"))"

Comment: updated the answer with the missing `)` at the end of the line.

Comment: Hmmm. Still received "SyntaxError: invalid syntax
:     print(element.get_attribute('innerHTML')))
"

Comment: Solved! There should be a ")" after element = WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//table[1]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td)[1]"))